# how to use Regular Expression match tld in url?

Tags: tld

how to use Regular Expression  match tld in url?

Need to match the tld, including almost all countries, organizations. Can do without the regular expression, but requires an efficient match

Comment: Please elaborate. Examples? Errors? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use a regex? Often using a regular expression is overkill. A few lines of code will be faster, and more maintainable than a big regular expression.

If your language has a split method just use that on a `"."` and the tld will be the last item in the array. If you're stuck in C++ or something just search backward from the end of the string to the first `.`, then the rest of the string from that point is the tld.

```
arr = url.split(".")
tld = arr[length - 1]
```

or

```
int period = url.find_from_last('.');
tld = url.substring(period, npos);
```

(I forgot the exact syntax for C++ `std::string`, but something similar to above)